# filter over a promise Emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to create a search coming from a JSON API. I have seen a few tutorials teaching how to do this and I got it working with their examples:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    searchResults: function(){
            var searchText = this.get('searchText');

            if ( ! searchText)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
                return ['hey', 'dude'].filter(function(c){
                    return c.match(regex);
                });
            }
        }.property('searchText')

});
```

This works great however when I try to do the same with a promise I get lost:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,

    searchResults: function(){
            var searchText = this.get('searchText');
            var adapter = AddressBookAdapter.create();
            var companies =  adapter.findAll();

            if ( ! searchText)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
                return companies.filter(function(c){
                    return c.match(regex);
                });
            }
        }.property('searchText')

});
```

Here is the adapter class:

```
export default Ember.Object.extend({
    findAll: function(){
        return ajax('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/address-book/companies')
            .then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });
    }
});
```

here is an example of the JSON API response structure:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "Alexandrine Skiles",
      links: [
        {
          rel: "self",
          uri: "/api/v1/address-book/alexandrine-skiles"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 33,
      name: "Ally Johns",
      links: [
        {
          rel: "self",
          uri: "/api/v1/address-book/ally-johns"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: companies.filter is not a function
```

I tried figuring out a way to convert a promise into an array so I can run the filter function but came up with nothing. What is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't "convert" a promise into an array. A promise is a promise object, that may be fulfilled at some point (if not already fulfilled). They can return results asynchronously.

So when you have the line:

```
var companies = adapter.findAll();
```

The `companies` variable is a promise that, **when fulfilled**, will return your data. In other words, `companies` has a `.then()` method you should be using.

So your ArrayController code would become something like this:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    searchText: null,
    searchResults: [],

    searchResultUpdater: function(){
        var searchText = this.get('searchText');
        var adapter = AddressBookAdapter.create();
        var companies =  adapter.findAll();

        if ( ! searchText)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            var regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');
            companies.then(function(data) {
                var results = data.filter(function(c){
                    return c.match(regex);
                });
                this.set('searchResults', results);
            });
        }
    }.property('searchText')
});
```

This sets a `searchResults` property when the promise is fulfilled. Of course, there are probably nicer ways of doing this - Ember provides a lot of tools.

Also you may want to do your `if (!searchText)` bit before you make any ajax requests if you're not going to use the result at all ;)

Comment: when I type n the input field nothing happens the update function is never called should I turn that onto an on-key action?

Comment: I made it an action but it gives me the error c.match is not a function

Comment: Use the debugger, man. Put a breakpoint there, explore the values. See what's happening. It will tell you everything you need to know. In this case, it's probably that c is an object, not a string. Maybe you want to do `c.Name.match()` instead